# validation rule to require an input IF another input has a specific value

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

In jquery.validate.js, I'm using this pattern for a series of rules:

```
rules: {
    memtype: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    },      
}
```

I'd like to add a rule that requires text input field 'sponout' to be filled only if memtype is checked and the value is "guide".  I've reviewed the 'depends' idea, but can't seem to suss out how to apply it here.

Comment: Refinement:  the input for memtype is a pair of radio buttons, so memtype will be selected, not checked.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make the value for the `required` rule be a [dependency-expression](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression).

It will look like this:

```
sponout: {
  required: 'input[name="memtype"][value="guide"]:checked'
}
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/UknKX/